# Elastic terminal

Tags: terminal-emulator

As a linux user, I frequently use terminal for wide variety of things.

Sometimes it's something small like apt-get install or echo'ing env variable (and I need small terminal) and sometimes I am grep'ing server logs (and need big terminal).

I thought it would be handy to terminal start with small size (let's say standard 60x48 or so) and then expand as needed (up to full screen) to display data. Shrinking is not really needed.

Is there already something like that?
Does it already have any formal name (I don't want to get sued by AWS^^ )?
Or maybe it's quite easy to configure with system options or tiny bash script?

Linux Mint.

Comment: I'm not aware of any terminal emulator automatically resizing based on its contents. Certain terminal emulators allow to resize by an escape sequence, e.g. to switch to 100x25 size try this: `echo -ne '\e[8;25;100t'`. You might alias `grep` and friends to emit this first if the output goes to the terminal.

Comment: `xterm` allows these sequences, but you have to enable "Allow Window Ops". `gnome-terminal` also supports these, but suffers from https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759146.

Comment: On a side note, this is where rewrapping on resize (a feature of certain terminal emulators including gnome-terminal) becomes really handy. You can enlarge the window after you've grepped the server logs, and the output will look just as if you've ran grep at the larger window size.

Comment: I would prefer it to resize without any sequence - automatically

Comment: I understand, but I'm pretty sure you won't find that anywhere. That's why I outlined some closeby possibilities.

Comment: Do you want horizontal resizing, vertical, or both? Vertical resizing isn't very useful in typical usage because scrollback accumulates quickly way past the number of lines that can fit on a screen. And full-screen applications expect a fixed terminal size, since they do things like “write this character at the bottom right corner”.

Comment: Both. Not sure about what full screen application are You talking about